# custom domain resolves through google but not company servers

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, bind, nameserver

I just set up a domain and when asking for the A records using the @8.8.8.8 server I get the correct record in no time. When I run +trace I see the company servers along the pathway, but when I run the same A record request and tag @ns1.company.com I dont get the A record. It refers me to the nameserver who is authoritative for that domain (correctly) but it doesnt give me the Answer Section and the appropriate A record. Is this normal? And if not what could be the bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ns1.company.com` is an authoritative-only server (which the name suggests it might be), it's normal that it doesn't answer for names that are not in any of its own zones.

If it's a name in a zone delegated from one of it's zones it will respond with a referral (like what the question seems to indicate), if it's just an entirely unrelated name the typical handling is to respond with status `REFUSED`.

Comment: I understand. One follow up question though. Google's 8.8.8.8 is also not responsible for my zone in particular but it follows down the path of requests and gives me the correct A record without delegating me to the ns that actually controls my domain. The ns1 of my company is clearly responsible for the ns that controls my domain so why doesnt it also follow through with it and provide the answer?

Comment: @Mnemosyne Google's `8.8.8.8` is an example of a different class of DNS server, it's not the *authoritative*  server but provides *recursion* service. Your company probably has some such server as well (denoted by an IP address found in the network configuration on client machines).